# angular js injector module error

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i am new to angular js i am trying to inject factory in a config ,but it shows module not found

factory code

```
var app=angular.module('app',['ui.router','angular-jwt','ngResource','angularValidator','satellizer']);

app.factory('AUTH_SERVICE', function ($auth,$state,$q) {
    var auth={};

 auth.isloggedin=function() {
     var defer = $q.defer();
    if($auth.isAuthenticated()){
   defer.resolve();
    }
    else
    {      
  $state.go('login');  
   defer.reject();     
    }

    return defer.promise;
}

 return auth;
});
```

config code is

```
app.config(['AUTH_SERVICE','$authProvider','$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider',function(AUTH_SERVICE,$stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider,$authProvider) {
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
    $stateProvider
    .state('home',{
        url:'/',
        templateUrl:'pages/home.html'

})
.state('login',{
    url:'/login',
    templateUrl:'pages/login.html',
    controller:'loginCtrl'
})
.state('register',{
    url:'/register',
    templateUrl:'pages/register.html',
    controller:'registerCtrl'

})

.state('dashboard',{
    url:'/Dashboard',
    templateUrl:'pages/dashboard.html',
    controller:'dashctrl',
    resolve:{
        skiplogin: _skiplogin
    }
})

function _skiplogin(AUTH_SERVICE){
return AUTH_SERVICEAUTH_SERVICE.isloggedin();
}



 }]);
```

but it shows error

> `angular.js:`38Uncaught Error: `[$injector:modulerr]`
>   http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.8/$injector/modulerr?p0=app&p1=Error%3A%20%…ocalhost%2Faccoex%2Fbower_components%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js%3A39%3A319)

Answer (score 3):

You can't inject `factory` object in the `app.config` because it can't be sure they have been loaded correctly..

In the `app.config` you can only inject `Consts` and `Providers`.

From the documentation

> A module is a collection of configuration and run blocks which get
>   applied to the application during the bootstrap process. In its
>   simplest form the module consist of collection of two kinds of blocks:
>
> Configuration blocks - get executed during the provider registrations
>   and configuration phase. Only providers and constants can be injected
>   into configuration blocks. This is to prevent accidental instantiation
>   of services before they have been fully configured.
>
> Run blocks - get executed after the injector is created and are used
>   to kickstart the application. Only instances and constants can be
>   injected into run blocks. This is to prevent further system
>   configuration during application run time.

Take a look to `provider` [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/providers) where you can configure a service in your `app.config`.

Comment: i cannot understand ialso tried injecting the service @suren-srapyan

Comment: @ArunkarthiMani no `factories`, no `services`, no `values` can be injected into the `.config`, only `providers` and `constants`

Answer (score 1):

you can't inject factory in config as it loads after config

angularjs application loads as follows:

Run

Config

Instantiate factory or service

Controller